# vue.js not included in javascript bundle from webpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to bundle up all my libraries and for the most part? It works.

However, `Vue` is not being included in the bundle (but everything else is). I can't figure out how to include `Vue` with the bundled JS from webpack.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");
var Vue = require('vue').default;
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./static/myapp/src/js/index.js",
  externals: {
    moment: "moment",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "static/myapp/dist/js/"),
    publicPath: "/static/myapp/dist/js/",
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)|(css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          { loader: "css-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve("jquery"),
        loader: "expose-loader",
        options: {
          exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name][hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "../css/[name].[contenthash].css",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: path.join(
        __dirname,
        "static/myapp/src/html/webpack_bundles.html"
      ),
      filename: path.join(
        __dirname,
        "templates/myapp/webpack_bundles.html"
      ),
      inject: false,
    }),
  ],
};
```

In my `index.js` I have this:

```
import "../scss/commonground.scss";
import "../css/style.css";
import "bootstrap";
import "select2";
import "vue";
import "bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css";
import "bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min";
import "select2/dist/css/select2.css";
```

All the other libraries (`bootstrap`, `select2`, `bootstrap-datepicker`) get bundled up, the CSS gets bundled together nicely, etc.

The bundle getting created (`main.<hash>.js`) does *not* include vuejs. How can I get it to?

I can't figure out how to get it to *include* vuejs. Any thoughts? Or any ideas that stick out? I've ran through numerous tutorials and how-to's, but can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.